# Unable to execute twistd - shows no output

Tags: python, windows, twisted, punjab

I have installed python 2.7, twisted 12.3. Also, i did install zope.interface 4.0.3.
I have added the follwowing to sys.path - C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twisted\scripts.

But when in command promot I run twistd command, I get no result.
Here is what I see -

C:\Users\Nitish>twistd

C:\Users\Nitish>

What has gone wrong here?
I need this to work inorder to run Punjab BOSH connection manager.

Comment: I suspect you're not actually running the twistd command line but are somehow instead running the twistd Python implementation file, which is not directly executable.  However, I don't quite understand how this is happening since you said you modified `sys.path`, not `%PATH%`, and I also haven't used the Twisted Windows installer for many years now.

Comment: I've set PATHEXT environment variable to include .py, as well as PATH evn variable to include C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twisted\scripts.
Do I explicitly have to set PYTHONPATH? What all needs to be set?

Comment: The main thing is that you need to run... `twistd.bat`... I think, not `twistd.py`.  But I could not say for sure if `twistd.bat` even still comes with the Windows installer, sorry.

Comment: No, twsited.bat isn't present. The present file is twistd.py.

Comment: Ohh.. crazy.. Finally I was able to figure out the reason.
I'd set Path env. variable to  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twisted\scripts whereas it should have been set to C:\Python27\Scripts
Now I am able ti execute the twistd command.